# How to integrate ajax control toolkit in existing project?

Tags: asp.net-ajax

How to integrate ajax control toolkit in existing project?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to register the assemblies and start using it.

The assemblies you need are :

AjaxControlToolkit
System.Web.Extensions

This seems like an easy way to do it however:

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/